# SQL Server: Given a year find everything (inclusive) from the year previous and given year

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm not familiar with SQL Server syntax, but I imagine it would go something like this:

```
$year = 2010;

$query = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM dbo.events 
                      WHERE date BETWEEN $year AND $year-1");
```

I'm just not sure how to format $year in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. Assuming the `date` column is a datetime datatype:

```
SELECT *
    FROM dbo.events
    WHERE DATEPART(year, date) BETWEEN $year-1 AND $year
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has the [YEAR function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx), which is even shorter to write than DATEPART:

```
select * from dbo.events where year(date) between $year-1 and $year
```

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to select only one year?

This works for me:

```
$year = 2011;
select * from table where year(date_field) = $year
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @year int
set @year=2010

select * from FROM dbo.events 
WHERE cast(YEAR([date]) as int) <= @year 
and cast(YEAR([date]) as int) >= @year-1
```