# DateTime query on only year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I want to select multiple records on the basis of a matching year. For example, in table `tab`, where columns are `[id] int`, `[name] varchar`, and `[bookyear] datetime`, I want to select all records with a year of 2009.

The following query gives 0 results:

```sql
SELECT 
    [ACCNO], 
    [Roll No],
    [IssueDate],
    [DueDate]
FROM 
    [test1].[dbo].[IssueHis$] 
WHERE 
    [IssueDate]  between 12-12-2004 and 1-01-2010
```

Comment: How can it be tagged both mysql and sql-server?

Comment: Take a look at the DATEPART function - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx - you can then do SELECT * FROM tab WHERE DATEPART(year, IssueDate) BETWEEN 2005 AND 2010 for example. Lots of examples on SO too, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043920/sql-server-given-a-year-find-everything-inclusive-from-the-year-previous-and

Comment: I tidied up the tags @rene as it's clear the question is about SQL Server.

Comment: @dash: you don't put fucntions on columns in SQL Server. It invalidates index usage

Comment: @user1074474: Why say "year 2009" and then "12-12-2004"?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
select id,name,bookyear from tab1 where year(bookyear) = 2009
```

Comment: Qeustion was edited :  when i read there is only like this I want to select all records where the year is 2009. so my query server that purpose.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT [ACCNO]
    ,[Roll No]
    ,[IssueDate]
    ,[DueDate]
FROM [test1].[dbo].[IssueHis$] 
WHERE [IssueDate] >= '20090101' AND
      [IssueDate] < '20100101'
```

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to delimit datetime constants like you would a string
2. Use `yyyymmdd` pattern for SQL Server (not `yyyy-mm-dd`, it is unsafe generally)
3. Use proper range queries to allow for time value

So, to find values between "12 Dec 2004" and "31 Dec 2009" *inclusive*, allowing for time:

```
...
where [IssueDate] >= '20041212' AND [IssueDate] < '20100101'
```

Edit, or this, because of the ambiguity in the question for "year = 2009"

```
...
where [IssueDate] >= '20090101' AND [IssueDate] < '20100101'
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation, and also, thanks for mentioning a function can have a negative impact on query performance vs. indexes. I didn't know that so am off to have a read :-)

Comment: @dash: Number 2 here http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/ten-common-sql-programming-mistakes/

Answer (score 2):

One of the most important things to remember with regards to SQL Server and dates is that the best format to use is this: `'YYYYMMDD'` (or `'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS'`). This format will always be interpreted properly by SQL Server, regardless of regional date settings.

```
SELECT [ACCNO] 
      ,[Roll No] 
      ,[IssueDate] 
      ,[DueDate] 
  FROM [test1].[dbo].[IssueHis$]  
 WHERE [IssueDate] >= '20090101' 
   AND [IssueDate] < '20100101'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a view that has the **IssueYear** as a separate column

```
CREATE VIEW vIssueHis
AS
SELECT
[ACCNO],
[Roll No],
[IssueDate],
[DueDate],
DATEPART(yyyy,IssueDate) as IssueYear,
DATEPART(yyyy,DueDate) as DueYear
FROM [test1].[dbo].[IssueHis$]
```

Then you could query the view like this

```
SELECT [ACCNO]
      ,[Roll No]
      ,[IssueDate]
      ,[DueDate]
FROM vIssueHis
WHERE IssueYear = 2009
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
....
WHERE [IssueDate] > '2004' AND [IssueDate] < 2010
```

Answer (score 0):

```
where YEAR(IssueDate) = '2009'
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/year-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you try this query:

```
SELECT to_date ('2008','yyyy') AS my_date, SYSDATE FROM dual;
```

The date will be the year (2008) and the current month (today is November), and the day is 1 so your query do not includes all months in 2008.