# how to search month with year in mysql

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

I have a table. It has a varchar type date column.
I want to search that table using date, but i want to search only from month with year.

**example:** `12-2016`
How can I write the query for that?
I want that part to assign to a variable of jasper

**example:**WHERE  .............  =$P{invDate}

**example as in my jasper report:**

SELECT invoiceheader.inNo AS invoiceheader_inNo, invoiceheader.cusID AS invoiceheader_cusID, invoiceheader.soNo AS invoiceheader_soNo, invoiceheader.total AS invoiceheader_total, invoiceheader.dis AS invoiceheader_dis, invoiceheader.netTotal AS invoiceheader_netTotal, invoiceheader.cash AS invoiceheader_cash, invoiceheader.bal AS invoiceheader_bal, invoiceheader.date AS invoiceheader_date FROM invoiceheader invoiceheader WHERE ...........................................=$P{invDate}

**I need a perfect query for the above space**

Comment: use like keyword for eample ( select * from table where date like '%12-2016');

Comment: Show some sample data in question please. *varchar type date column* is not very clear

Comment: Maybe you want to use [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime query on only year in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654627/datetime-query-on-only-year-in-sql-server)

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: SELECT
     invoiceheader.`inNo` AS invoiceheader_inNo,
     invoiceheader.`cusID` AS invoiceheader_cusID,
     invoiceheader.`soNo` AS invoiceheader_soNo,
     invoiceheader.`total` AS invoiceheader_total,
     invoiceheader.`dis` AS invoiceheader_dis,
     invoiceheader.`netTotal` AS invoiceheader_netTotal,
     invoiceheader.`cash` AS invoiceheader_cash,
     invoiceheader.`bal` AS invoiceheader_bal,
     invoiceheader.`date` AS invoiceheader_date
FROM
     `invoiceheader` invoiceheader
WHERE
   ...........................................=$P{invDate}

Comment: need a quary for space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (you have used varchar data type for date so like keyword will perfectly suitable for this situation):

```
 select * from table where date like concat('%' ,$P{invDate});
```

Comment: i'm not giving the date in query, i pass that from a parameter.. so i need a query suitable for any month and year

Comment: @Nisal what does your column contain?

Comment: Answer Updated now please try this @ Nisal

Comment: SELECT invoiceheader.inNo AS invoiceheader_inNo, invoiceheader.cusID AS invoiceheader_cusID, invoiceheader.soNo AS invoiceheader_soNo, invoiceheader.total AS invoiceheader_total, invoiceheader.dis AS invoiceheader_dis, invoiceheader.netTotal AS invoiceheader_netTotal, invoiceheader.cash AS invoiceheader_cash, invoiceheader.bal AS invoiceheader_bal, invoiceheader.date AS invoiceheader_date FROM invoiceheader invoiceheader WHERE ...........................................=$P{invDate}

Comment: need a query for the space

Answer (score 0):

Try this case:

```
STR_TO_DATE(date_field, '%d-%m-%Y') < STR_TO_DATE('12-2016', '%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following -

```
select * from Table_name where month(date_column_name)=12 and year(date_column_name)=2016
```