# SQL Query employees who joined in x year y month not giving desired result

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Query**

List the emps who joined in the year 1992

**Employees Table**

```
EmployeeID  LastName    Title                        BirthDate               HireDate
1            Davolio    Sales Representative        1948-12-08 00:00:00.000 1992-05-01 00:00:00.000
2            Fuller     Vice President, Sales       1952-02-19 00:00:00.000 1993-08-14 00:00:00.000
3            Leverling  Sales Representative        1963-08-30 00:00:00.000 1992-04-01 00:00:00.000
```

**Query Code**

```
Select * from employees 
where HireDate like '1992%'
```

**Result**
I am getting null result. How to get result where year starts with 1992

Same way to find out employees hired in May - 1992

```
Select * from employees where HireDate like '1992-05%'
```

Results in null and no columns

Comment: Hint : `datepart(year, date_col)` or `year()`.

Comment: Don't treat dates as strings.

Comment: [DateTime query on only year in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8654627/205233)

Comment: please read my question, I need only year and also year-month

Comment: Your original query is wrong: Fuller is hire in 1992

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While converting to a `varchar` appears a straightforward solution, its performance will not be optimal, because its not sargable - indexes can't be used once you start transforming columns i.e. by converting them, when used in a `where` clause.

Using a window compare removes the need for a function and performs better as follows:

```
-- Find all employees hired in 2020
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Employees 
WHERE Hiredate >= '01 Jan 2020' and HireDate < '01 Jan 2021'

-- Find all employees hired in May 2020
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Employees 
WHERE Hiredate >= '01 May 2020' and HireDate < '01 Jun 2020'
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to change the dateformat of the data that you are querying to give you only the year.

We can do this by using `DATEPART(YY)`

like this

```
DATEPART(YY,hiredate)
```

Also, you will need to replace LIKE for an exact matching system by using `=`

```
WHERE DATEPART(YY,hiredate) = ('1992')
```

Therefore your end script should be;

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM employees 
WHERE DATEPART(YY,hiredate) = ('1992')
```

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` is a string function.  But your column is presumably a date/time value of some sort.  It is much better to use comparisons -- using standard date/time formats.  For your question:

```
where HireDate >= '1992-01-01' and HireDate < '1993-01-01'
```

or:

```
where HireDate >= '19920101' and HireDate < '19930101'
```

The hyphen form uses ISO standard date formats that work under most conditions in SQL Server (there is one internationalization setting in SQL Server where it doesn't work).  The second uses SQL Server's internal standard date which works under all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

how can u produce a list of members who joined after x date f.e. after the start of the september

```
SELECT nameid, surname, firstname, joindate
FROM Table
WHERE joindate >= '2012-09-01';
```

or u can use extract function for ur condition